# How to pass a variable from VBS to VBA?

Tags: vba, variables, vbscript

I am trying to use a variable (instancia) defined in VBS in VBA, but I do not know how to do it. This is the code:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Workbooks.Open (folder & "\Generate.xlsm")
objExcel.Visible = True
maxinstancia = objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value

   For instancia=1 to maxinstancia
    objExcel.Run "GenerateClients"
   Next

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(True)
objExcel.Quit
```

The variable I am defining in VBS is "instancia" which is part of a loop. Then, the macro "GenerateClients" is run from Excel, and there is a variable called "instancia" there, that should be the same as in VBS, but it doesnt work...

Comment: Have you tried just adding instancia as an argument? objExcel.Run "GenerateClients", instancia

Comment: It doesn't work... An error appears in that line: incorrect number of arguments... any idea? thanks!

Comment: No, sorry: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197132.aspx